# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi}(t\sin{t})^3\cdot{\mathrm dt\over (1+\cos^2t)^2}$

Tags: integration

What is the exact closed form for $(1)$
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}(t\sin{t})^3\cdot{\mathrm dt\over (1+\cos^2t)^2}\approx{2\pi^2\over 2\phi+1}?\tag1$$

$\phi={1+\sqrt{5}\over 2}$

This integral is quite of complicate, any hint on what substitution to used.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{2} \pi  \left(\pi ^2-6 i \sqrt{2} \left(\text{Li}_2\left(-i \left(-1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(i \left(-1+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: Wait does the approximation sign actually indicate it’s approximately equal to, or is exactly equal to?

Comment: @Crescendo The exact value is what I found with *Mathematica* above and is about $4.65985$. The OP value $\frac{2 \pi ^2}{2 \phi +1}$ is very close to the actual value.

Comment: By exploiting symmetry and by applying integration by parts twice, the whole problem boils down to computing $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log(\sqrt{2}\pm\sin\theta)\,d\theta$. The dilogarithms machinery then proves Raffaele's claim.